# Long-term frequentist decision strategy. How to "unreject" H0 when false positive occurs?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, frequentist, decision-theory

TLDR: How to quantify the H0/H1 plausibility, when there are multiple statistics available on the matter? What is a good source to learn more about frequentist decision making strategy?

Once in a while we hear about flawed studies, wasting a lot of resources on follow-up research e.g. testing a drug that turns out to not work. False positive (negative) results are unavoidable in statistics, leading to "debunking" articles, replications or metanalyses "showing no significance" being published, refuting previous beliefs.

Bayesian statistics provides (at least in theory) pretty intuitive framework to deal with such decision-making process: take prior beliefs and correct them with the new data. We can even weight the beliefs by the cost of false positives and negatives. What is frequentist response here?

Say the hypothesis $ H_0 $ was rejected at $\alpha$ and I acted as if it was false, but after some time I start questioning my choice. What is the proper methodology to change my decision? What is there are multiple studies available, assigning $p$-values $0.05, 0.08, 0.7$ and $0.006$ to the same hypothesis $H_0$?

Comment: Meta-analysis will do something of this kind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis

Comment: Aside from using meta analysis to combine information, there is still the issue that frequentist statistics is divorced from decision making, as p-values are computed by conditioning on what you are trying to learn.  Bayesian posterior probabilities carry along their own error probabilities, e.g., if you act as if a treatment works because Pr(tx works | data, prior) = 0.97, you can keep in mind for the future that the probability you were wrong is 0.03. Bayes also provides a unique way to update the probabilities as more information comes in.